# Error getting an ad response Admob

Tags: android, admob

When I try implementing admit to android application am running into this error.If I insert test device hash I only see admob testing ads only. When I comment out test for production this is the error I get on the 
Error log

```
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Here is my code code for implementing the advert

```
public void showAds() {
    String deviceId = MGUtilities.getDeviceID(getApplicationContext());
    Log.e("DEVICE ID", "------------------------------------------");
    Log.e("DEVICE ID", deviceId);
    Log.e("DEVICE ID", "------------------------------------------");
    FrameLayout frameAds = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameAds);
    if (Config.WILL_SHOW_ADS) {
        frameAds.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (adView == null) {
            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            adView.setAdUnitId(Config.BANNER_UNIT_ID);
            frameAds.addView(adView);

            AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            if (Config.TEST_ADS_USING_TESTING_DEVICE)
                builder.addTestDevice(Config.TESTING_DEVICE_HASH);

            if(Config.TEST_ADS_USING_EMULATOR)
                builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

            AdRequest adRequest = builder.build();
            // Start loading the ad in the background.
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    } else {
        frameAds.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

What might be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your problem briefly, you can post here its relevant code too. So, I better understand

Comment: [It's old](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18591724/3290339) but might be helpful.

Comment: check out this post: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972862/admob-getting-an-ad-response-errorcode-0-failed-to-load-ad0

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine you have to wait for sometime after generating ad id because usually admob need time to show live ads to you. If you are now able to see ads after maximum 24 hours then please contact admob customer care for help.

Comment: I have been waiting for 3 days now.

Comment: now you have to contact admob customer care  because may be their is issue with your account.

Comment: have you checked by adding another ad id which is working on your another app ?

Comment: This my fist time am using admob.

Comment: Than you have to contact admob customer care about this issue,if your test ads are working fine. They will solve your issue.

Comment: Without wasting any time please contact them as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are using live Admob ads id in Debug mode, it will show this error.

For live Admob ids to load create a Release apk and try to check in that.

Comment: Can you please update your cod fully ? Are your initializing ads with correct App ID ?

Comment: When did you created Banner ID ?

Comment: I created this 3 day ago.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972862/admob-getting-an-ad-response-errorcode-0-failed-to-load-ad0/38692763 Did you tried all this ?