# AdMob Ads not displaying on Android Studio

Tags: android, admob

I was having difficulty adding admob ads into an android app and was continually receiving the error message: `There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0` followed by `Failed to load ad: 0`., so I copied the code directly from the tutorial and am still getting the same errors. I am using everything as provided by android studio in this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="michaelsinn.contact.gmail.com.testads.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("[Correct test device id is here]").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [admob getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0 Failed to load ad:0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972862/admob-getting-an-ad-response-errorcode-0-failed-to-load-ad0)

Comment: Yeah I looked there before but I couldnt find anything to help

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ad Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ad Failed to load",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ad Opened",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
        // covers the screen.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ad Left Application",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ad Closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
        // to the app after tapping on an ad.
    }
});
```

Comment: I added the code in, and received the output of "Ad Failed to load"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine

try running the app on emulator and see the result

**another thing**

go to admob

settings

test deices

ADD TEST DEVICE

and then go with the instruction to add your own device as a test device

if the ad worked fine with the **test ad** banner then you are okay

if not then check your mainfest

and make sure you added

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx~xxxxx" />
```