# admob banner live ad not showing but test showing

Tags: android, admob

MainActivity code:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

main_activity.xml file

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7758424290736454/1358492948" />
```

when i add Test ID ad is showing.:

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

i am getting below error logs

```
DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
    01-29 16:19:28.141 6523-6523/com.recreation.cryptocurrencyrate I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds$Settings) ((null):-1)
    01-29 16:19:28.141 6523-6523/com.recreation.cryptocurrencyrate I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) ((null):-1)
    01-29 16:19:28.142 6523-6523/com.recreation.cryptocurrencyrate I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds$Settings) ((null):-1)
    01-29 16:19:28.142 6523-6523/com.recreation.cryptocurrencyrate I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) ((null):-1)
    01-29 16:19:30.961 6523-6523/com.recreation.cryptocurrencyrate I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    01-29 16:19:30.961 6523-6523/com.recreation.cryptocurrencyrate I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
    01-29 16:19:30.972 6523-6523/com.recreation.cryptocurrencyrate W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
    01-29 16:19:33.499 6523-6540/com.recreation.cryptocurrencyrate W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
    01-29 16:19:33.506 6523-6523/com.recreation.cryptocurrencyrate W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Admob App Unit id dashboard.

[image: admob account dasboard]

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  How did you solve this error?

Comment: check this for your solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38692763/8265484)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Adunit Id is newly created so it will take time to review adunit and displaying ads in your app. Problem is with your created adunit Id. Its displaying test ads to me in my app with your AdUnit Id.

Follow below steps :-

To create a Live Ad unit id

Sign In to

https://apps.admob.com

in the left side menu click on ->Apps
add app
choose whether you have published your app on Google Play or the App Store
if no -> Enter your app information
Create Ad unit
replace the test Ad unit with the new Ad unit.
you get to see the AD once the app is published to playstore!

Comment: almost one day passed

Comment: did you check this id :ca-app-pub-7758424290736454/1358492948 ?

Comment: You need to create new live ads ID.

Comment: i created two new ids as well. and my current app is already published on play store

Comment: check in debug apk , is it displaying ads or not with newly created id?

Comment: newly created id ca-app-pub-7758424290736454/3400264558 still not showing

Comment: i think you have issue with your account , contact to support team regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

May you check if you add codes below to your androidmanifest.xml;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in

It seems you added already

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

to your build.gradle

If all done, ads should work.