# AdMob test ads have gone in a new app

Tags: android, banner, smartbanner

Some time ago I created several applications using Appodeal plugin and they all work. They show only banners and smart_banners but with low fill rate. Therefore week ago I started develop my first app with direct AdMob integration. I created code and tested it with test AdMob UnitID `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111` Even I tested it with real UnitID but with test device ID (128 bits hexadecimal number) which I've got from **AdMob**. All worked well. I even tried once run it with real UnitID bit without test device ID to be sure it shows real ads. I've got 1 real ad then turned app off. After last weekend I returned to further development. I changed UnitID to AdMob testing ID again. But once I added some functions then assembled and run app - I've got ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR 0 inside onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) method. Nothing was changed in AdMob call sequences in my app. Even I rolled back to the code from previous week. This didn't help. My app now does not work with AdMob. It receives ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR 0 after each banner load attempt. This is true for banners and smart_banners, for AdMob test UnitID and device test ID with real UnitID.

Before error app tells following in console:

```
I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
```

then it delays for some seconds and tells:

```
I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (500) https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html

W Ads : There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0

W Ads : Failed to load ad: 0
```

What can be wrong? How can I define what can be wrong? I break my head on monitor glass but cannot find any mistake in code. It works like it worked before but with another result. At Friday I've got test and real banners but at Monday I get only error 0. HELP!!!

By the way - my AdMob account is not blocked. I can access it and I see all my previous apps statistics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [admob getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0 Failed to load ad:0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972862/admob-getting-an-ad-response-errorcode-0-failed-to-load-ad0)

Comment: How we going to help you when we don't see how you are initializing/using it?

Comment: There is a lot of code and settings. Ask me what I should show here - then I will copy-paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow... Something new strange behavior. Now I tested little more and got new results:

- With request to AdMob test UnitID application shows test banners (Hooraah!)
- With request to my UnitID for SMART_BANNER from TEST device the application... receives error 3 "no fill from ad server". But... this is a TEST request. It even is visible in app console messages:

> I Ads     : This request is sent from a test device.

- With request to my UnitID for BANNER from TEST device the application... shows real banner :-o But again this is TEST device. It is again visible in app console:

> I Ads     : This request is sent from a test device.

**I
CHANGED
NOTHING** 
in my app except UnitID and banner type. Nothing more from yesterday.

Looks like something was broken in AdMob test services but was not completely fixed yet.