# Android 8 samsung admob not showing ads

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-8.0-oreo, admob

I have an application with admob.
It works on all devices, but it doesn't show ads on android 8 samsung devices.

It also works samsung's other versions and other brands all versions including android 8.

I get following error.

```
2018-10-12 21:21:47.508 13284-31190/? E/Ads: Error waiting for future.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.af.get(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):18)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.g.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):11)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):62)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):169)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.f.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366015@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.m.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301
```

For ads, I use following version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/roundicon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DepartmentCoursesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ExamDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AddLessonActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CourseExamListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ImageZoomActivity"></activity>

        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="[MY_AD_ID]"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And also there is following log, it may be related

```
2018-10-12 21:21:46.618 1764-1764/? E/ServiceUtils: [#MLP#] Unable to get package name: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.samsung.ipservice (com.samsung.ipservice)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser (ApplicationPackageManager.java:301)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:272)
        at com.samsung.mlp.platform.utils.ServiceUtils.isPackageAvailable (ServiceUtils.java:55)
        at com.samsung.mlp.platform.framework.ItemFetchTask.buildImageSelectionSchema (ItemFetchTask.java:147)
        at com.samsung.mlp.platform.framework.ItemFetchTask.buildMediaSelectionSchema (ItemFetchTask.java:129)
        at com.samsung.mlp.platform.framework.ItemFetchTask.<init> (ItemFetchTask.java:107)
        at com.samsung.mlp.platform.framework.LPServiceController.setupExecutors (LPServiceController.java:200)
        at com.samsung.mlp.platform.framework.LPServiceController.<init> (LPServiceController.java:179)
        at com.samsung.mlp.platform.framework.LPServiceController.getInstance (LPServiceController.java:168)
        at com.samsung.mlp.platform.LPService.onBind (LPService.java:49)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService (ActivityThread.java:3571)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2 (null:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1791)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:-2)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50346048/4385913

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

 <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Hope this will work...!