# Android Admob Error code 0

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

The admob get error on onrewardedvideoadfailedtoload method . The error gettings just tablets. But i don't know why. Is there any idea about that ?

> The error code is 0

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972862/admob-getting-an-ad-response-errorcode-0-failed-to-load-ad0

Answer (score 0):

When you create newly app id its take time to live, almost one day. There is no error in your code. Your request is successfull thats the server reply with 0-4 code error if thers any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Android 9 (Android Pie) and can get ads on older devices running Android 8 or older, then an issue has been submitted to AdMob here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/JAnmzrS4Tuk